# problemas al ejecutar Derby en Java!

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña Aplicación en Java en Netbeans, no tengo problemas para crear la base de datos y vincular en modo de desarrollo, el detalle es cuando genero el ejecutable(EXE) me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo cuales son las razones que me falta al agregar para vincule la base de datos

Comment: No existen ejecutables en Java, por ende no entiendo cómo puedes generar un EXE. Fuera de eso, Derby es una librería, cuando generas tu librería no se incluyen las librerías de las cuales depende tu proyecto. Debes agregar esas librerías manualmente, quizás colocando en una carpeta lib, y luego agregar estas librerías al classpath de la aplicación.

Comment: Pues el exe se genera con una aplicación(Launch4j) si en modo desarrollo funciona correctamente

Comment: Esa aplicación no es propia del JDK ni de Java, es un externo. Con eso me refiero a que Java no tiene ejecutables.

Comment: Claro, pero aún así mi duda sigue como es que pierde el vínculo o sencillamente trabaja

Comment: Está en la segunda parte de mi comentario.

Comment: si las librerias las agrego correctamente, si no me funcionaran cuando estoy probando la aplicacion y corre guarda consulta, pero al crear el ejecutable no indica como agregarlas

Comment: De nuevo, las librerías **no se agregan cuando generas tu librería**, es decir, el jar de tu proyecto. Lo que hace el IDE por detrás es agregar las librerías que "agregaste" al classpath de tu aplicación. Para entender mejor esto, te recomiendo que revises [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).

Comment: ok, gracias, bueno apenas me meti a java y desconosco detalles como esos, muchas gracias